# How to save captured image to a imageview in andother directory?

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, save, android-camera

[image]

My application is based on android studio, 
I really appreciate your help and consideration :)
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting captured image[from camera] to image view:

```
 Intent getImageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(getImageIntent, 1);

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                imageCounter++;
                takePicture(data);
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

            }
        }
    }

    protected void takePicture(Intent data) {
        Bundle b = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap pic = (Bitmap) b.get("data");
        if (pic != null) {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
            ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.captured_image_layout))
            .addView(img);
            img.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.33f));
            img.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            img.setImageBitmap(pic);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you shubham :) I really appreciate it! it works :D Thank you so much :)